# VB.NET ITextSharp Add footer at very last page

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I want to add footer to my last page at my document. using my code will make footer on every page at my document. I thought of using OnCloseDocument but I'm not sure how to code it, or maybe it's wrong. please help me, thank you.

```
Public Class itsEvents
    Inherits PdfPageEventHelper
    Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(ByVal writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
        'Dim ch As New Chunk("This is my Stack Overflow Header on page " & writer.PageNumber)
        'document.Add(ch)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub OnEndPage(ByVal writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
        Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
        Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
        cb.BeginText()
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12)
        cb.SetTextMatrix(50, 75)
        cb.ShowText("Marketing")
        cb.SetTextMatrix(400, 90)
        cb.ShowText("Surabaya,")
        cb.SetTextMatrix(400, 75)
        cb.ShowText("Penanggungjawab")
        cb.EndText()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub OnCloseDocument(ByVal writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why are you using a page event if you only want to add a footer to the last page? If you *insist* on using page events, move your code to the `OnCloseDocument` method. Personally, I wouldn't use page events to add that footer. I'd just add the content before closing the document. Also: I know you commented out the code, but **NEVER ADD CONTENT IN THE OnStartPage METHOD!** Finally: why are you using an old iText version? This functionality has been replaced by "handlers" in iText 7.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm still learning about using ITextSharp, i want to add signature at the bottom last of my page. If i add the content before closing the document, it wouldn't be on the bottom of that last page. I will delete content in the OnStartPage method.

Comment: Since you are just starting, you are still in time to throw away all of your iText 5 (or earlier) code, and start with iText 7. Your requirement is much easier to achieve with iText 7.